# How to copy certain subset of system files to another directory

Tags: windows, command

I have a task of copying all system files starting with letter 'b' to another disk. That is purely training task, I do not care whether in the new location these are useful to anything at all. It should be done with windows command line or its scripts.

I spent some time and found only 'dir' command having direct access to system file category; but 'dir' in my humble understanding produces only text output and can be directed to text file and not command like copy. How then to solve the issue?

Comment: Have you tried the `copy` command?

Comment: How to access file attributes in copy? That is the point for me

Comment: Then try `xcopy` if that not enough for you you may need to create a script

Comment: Xcopy dosn't have a query for system files I am afraid, besides it takes rather directory treee. In fact that could meet literally criteria for answer, but then a question how to remove a rest of stuff it copies.